# Add item to navigationView

Tags: android

I have made this .xml that contains items of my navigationView.

```
  <item android:title="Title">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/a"
                android:title="A"
                android:orderInCategory="1"
                />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/b"
                android:title="B"
                android:orderInCategory="1"
                />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/c"
                android:title="C"
                android:orderInCategory="1"
                />
        </group>

    </menu>
</item>
```

I want to add items bellow item C on the same group programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();

//params: groupId, itemId, order, title
menu.add(R.id.menu, 123, Menu.NONE, "Item");
```

to remove the divider add this line to your style xml:

```
<item name="android:listDivider">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Comment: But that inserts one horizontal bar above "Item".

Comment: if you mean the divider, it's added between two groups.. so if you see that divider this may mean that you are creating a new group, make sure the group id is the same as in your menu xml

Comment: Yes I am talking about the divider.

Comment: I don't know why that divider appear but you can just make it transparent, see the edited answer

Comment: With that solution if I add other menu all dividers will be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Use method

```
navigationView.getMenu().add(int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title);
```

Like

```
getMenu.add(R.id.submenu_others, R.id.action_logout, Menu.NONE, "logout");
```